# get value of Sharepoint content field on a publishing page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, field

I am working on a page layout for a publshing page and in the page layout are a couple of fields like Address1, Address2 etc which are all 'multiple lines of text' type. Now I need to use the values of those fields in resulting pages once the authors write them. I also need to use those address values and plot them in google maps. How do I get the values of those fields that authors fill up so as to plot those values in google map using like javascript?

Comment: Address1 and Address2 are fields in a list? or aspnet controls on your layout page?

Comment: No Address1 is a Sharepoint content field control that is in a publishing page layout and authors will later fill its value by creating a new page or editing the page..i am looking to get the ID of the field as it is rendered in HTML so i can get its value by elementID using javascript??? Any Ideas??

Comment: you can use ClientID to get the ID of these Fields... <%= Address1.clientID %> will give you the clientID, you can use this ID in your javascript

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you have to add an script to the bottom of your template, preferably on the EditModePanel "Display", if you have something like this:

```
<SharePoint:TextField Id="Address1"/>
<SharePoint:TextField Id="Address2"/>
```

To find elements where the id attribute 'end with a name':

```
<script>

 $("[id$=Address1]").val(); //Address1 value
 $("[id$=Address2]").val(); //Address2 value

</script>
```

It is also a good idea (performance-wise) to have an Id wrapping your text fields, to make the DOM scan faster:

```
<script>

 $("#Location").find("[id$=Address1]").val(); //Address1 value
 $("#Location").find("[id$=Address2]").val(); //Address2 value

</script>
```